# Minor inconvenience of .between? method

Tags: ruby

```
n = 4
n.between?(3,5) # => true
n.between?(5,3) # => false
```

Wouldn't it be more convenient if the `.between?` method returned `true` in the third line? If not, why not?

**EDIT for clarification**

Here is the source code (forgive me but C is not my native tongue)

```
               static VALUE
cmp_between(VALUE x, VALUE min, VALUE max)
{
    if (RTEST(cmp_lt(x, min))) return Qfalse;
    if (RTEST(cmp_gt(x, max))) return Qfalse;
    return Qtrue;
}
```

What would be the negative side effects (besides that it might break a lot of extant legacy code) if this were changed to

```
               static VALUE
cmp_between(VALUE x, VALUE y, VALUE z)
{    
    if (RTEST(cmp_lt(y, z))) {
        y = min;
        z = max; }
    else {
        z = min;
        y = max; }
    if (RTEST(cmp_lt(x, min))) return Qfalse;
    if (RTEST(cmp_gt(x, max))) return Qfalse;
    return Qtrue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is mathematical. Suppose you want to check that something is in the interval [0, Y]. Mathematically, this only makes sense if Y is greater than or equal to 0. The way `between?` works, you can check that very easily with

```
n.between?(0, y)
```

If it worked the way you described, then the intervals [0, Y] and [Y, 0] would be treated the same (which would really confuse mathematicians). And you would need two checks:

```
y >= 0 and n.between?(0, y)
```

But if you don't care at all about how mathematicians feel, you can easily make it order-independent:

```
n.between?(*[x,y].sort)
```

Comment: But ruby isn't even reading 0 and y as a range - it's running a kind of `case...when` on two different `<=>` operators. I guess my question is a somewhat philosophical one. Considering all the surprisingly sweet syntactical sugar in the Ruby language, what would be the DISadvantage of having the `between?` method automatically sort the two parameter values?

Comment: I suspect the reason it isn't reading it as a range is actually for performance purposes since in some cases range inclusion uses `succ`. Compare `'bbbbbb'.between?('a','zzzzzzzzzzzz')` (instantaneous) to `('a'..'zzzzzzzzzzzz').include? 'bbbbbb'` (takes several seconds on my desktop).